# WCF service listener

Tags: wcf

I need to make a WCF service which will wait (listen) for an object to be sent from a web site and when the object is received, it has to contact another service and send some data. Can anyone help me with some starting code at least, please?

Comment: My problem is with the listening part - how can I make it do something when the object is received?

Comment: You expose a service operation which is called by code executing on the website back end.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving you code [here is a video.](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/02/03/video-creating-a-service-with-windows-communication-service-wcf.aspx) It shows how to acomplish exposing a simple service. You can copy his code along with learning some of what you are doing.

Once you have a service **exposed=listening**, you can write code to have it **consume=contact another service**. This will happen within the method your exposed service fires when it is called. Call the second service and provide it data.

If the data is the object the website sent to your service. Than you can skip a step and just call from the website :)

Also read the following links. Even if you do not understand all of it that is ok. I did not the first time I read them either.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668810.aspx